# Lower bound for negative part of a real function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, upper-lower-bounds

Let $u:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function and let $u_-$ its negative part.

My question is: what is an lower bound ($u_-\ge \dots$) for $u_-$? I mean, it is possible to estimate $u_-$ by using $\inf(u_-), \sup(u_-)$ or somethinf similar?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: $f(x) \ge \inf f$ holds for all function, in particular for $f = u_-$.

Comment: What is your definition of $u_-$? In some works, one uses $u_- = \max( -u , 0)$ and with this definition, $u_- \ge 0$.

Comment: @gerw it is the one used here. With that definition, I am also interested in understand what is $-u_-$ and what is the relation between $u_-$ and $-u_-$ (I always mean if something like $-u_-\ge u_-$ or vice versa holds). It is $-u_- = -\max(-u, 0)$, but how to write better this in a more fruitable way? I hope you could help.

Comment: With my definition, you always have $u_ \ge 0 \ge - u_-$ and $-u_- = \min(u, 0)$.